# value not found in Terminated method in akka actor example

Tags: scala, akka, actor

hi i am new to scala and akka and i am creating an actor that terminates after the processing of messages but i am having error in PoisonPill and Terminated case, it gives value not found error
i am confused that if i declear it then what should be the parameter type

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props

case class Greet(name: String)
case class Praise(name: String)
case class Celebrate(name: String, age: Int)

class Talker extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Greet(name)=>println(s"Hello $name")
    case Praise(name) => println(s"$name, you're amazing")
    case Celebrate(name, age) => println(s"Here's to another $age years, $name")
  }
}

object HelloActors extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloActors")
  system.actorOf(Props[Master], "master")
}

class Master extends Actor {
  val talker = context.actorOf(Props[Talker], "talker")
  override def preStart {
    context.watch(talker)
    talker ! Greet("Huey")
    talker ! Praise("Dewey")
    talker ! Celebrate("Louie", 16)
    talker ! PoisonPill
  }

  def receive = {
    case Terminated(`talker`) => context.system.shutdown
  }
}
```

here are the errors

> [error] /home/ahsen/SbtPrctc/PoisionPill/src/main/scala/HelloActors.scala:27: not found: value PoisonPill
>   [error] talker ! PoisonPill
>   [error]          ^
>   [error] /home/ahsen/SbtPrctc/PoisionPill/src/main/scala/HelloActors.scala:30: not found: value Terminated
>   [error] case Terminated(`talker`) => context.system.shutdown
>   [error]      ^
>   [error] two errors found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `PoisonPill` object:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, Actor, PoisonPill, ActorSystem, Terminated}
```

Or:

```
import akka.actor._
```